# Zookeeper - Does anyone use it for more than one tool? (e.g., Kafka and Hadoop)

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Does anyone have experience using the same zookeeper cluster for more than one tool ? e.g. using the same zookeeper cluster for Kafka and Hadoop.

kafka comes with it's own zookeper startup scripts and configurations, but I'm thinking of reusing and existing zookeper cluster for multiple tools.

Okay idea? or bad?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This is a common practice in most Hadoop clusters to manage most if not all the services with one set of zookeeper servers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in my previous project we had installed Kafka along with hadoop using the same CDH and used same set of zookeeper to manage kafka and hadoop.just make sure to use a separate charoot path for kafka

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).